# Is there a way to put Jbuttons on a JLabel(with a background picture)?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am currently working on a java project, I’m using javaswing in netbeans. I have a housemappicture set as a background on a Jlabel, but I want to put Jbuttons on each room. Is there anyway I can do it? If I put a Jbutton on the Jlabel the label just moved away

Comment: Moves*, and I’m just a beginner so I’m not very familiar with programming

Comment: Best not to use a JLabel as a container but rather draw the image in a JPanel and put your buttons on the panel. A JPanel makes for a much better *container* than a JLabel.

Comment: And yes, this involves code that is more complex than dragging and dropping a component in the GUI builder. Best to jump in with both feet and learn.